# Adding multiple extensions to PHP.INI

Tags: php.ini

I have two extensions I want to add. Do I add these separately like:

```
extension=php_ftp.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Or are they added like an array?

```
extension=php_ftp.dll,php_openssl.dll
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php.ini indicates that there should be only 1 extension declaration per line:

```
 866 ; If you wish to have an extension loaded automatically, use the following
 867 ; syntax:
 868 ;
 869 ;   extension=modulename.extension
 870 ;
 871 ; For example, on Windows:
 872 ;
 873 ;   extension=mysqli.dll
 874 ;
 875 ; ... or under UNIX:
 876 ;
 877 ;   extension=mysqli.so
 878 ;
 879 ; ... or with a path:
 880 ;
 881 ;   extension=/path/to/extension/mysqli.so
```

Via: http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=blob;f=php.ini-production;hb=HEAD#l865